# git command line equivalent to github changed files

Tags: git, github

Assuming my local repo is up-to-date, is there a git command I can issue from the command line that will give the same list of files changed as github does under the "Files changed" tab for a PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a git command I can issue from the command line that will give the same list of files changed as github does under the "Files changed" tab

`git show` does this. It's a very useful command that can be used to see relevant information about various git objects. Used by itself, it shows the changes in the most recent commit in the current branch, but you can use it to look at other commits, tags, etc. If you just want a list of the files that were changed, use the `--name-only` flag, like `git show --name-only`.

Of course, if you want to see the same list of files that GitHub shows in the "Files Changed" tab, you'll need to point the command at the same list of commits that are in the pull request. I use:

```
git show --name-only <base>...
```

where `<base>` is the commit hash of my branch's base commit, i.e. the one that my branch and the branch that's the base for my pull request have in common. I generally just find that by examining the result of `git log` to find the commit before the first one in my pull request, but you can also get it with:

```
git merge-base destination source
```

where `destination` is the base of the pull request and `source` is the branch from which I'm making the pull request.

The three dots (`...`) in the command tell git to use all the commits in the branch after the specified one, so `git show --name-only <base>...` shows me the names of the files affected by the unmerged commits in my branch, which is the same thing that the "Files Changed" tab does.

Comment: I'm looking for a git command that will give **exactly** the same file list that github displays.  I've tried various combinations of `git diff A B --name-only`, `git diff A..B --name-only`, `git diff A...B --name-only`, etc, and the results are always noisier (from people merging develop into the feature branch in the PR) than what's on github.

Comment: The 3-dot version is the winner: `git diff --name-only upstream-branch...feature-branch` should give you _the same_ list of files as github. If it doesn't give you the same list then you are comparing differemt things (did you fetch? Using the exact same commits? Sure sure?)

Comment: @caleb using `git show` only works if the PR has a single commit.

Comment: @user1071847 Some of the particulars may come down to the way that you use git. On my team, we generally create a new branch for each new task/feature, and then create a pull request from that branch back to the main branch. With that in mind, `git show --name-only <hash>...`, where `<hash>` is the base commit for the branch my PR is made from, shows me **exactly** the files that are included in the PR. I'm sorry if my leaving the arguments out of the command caused any confusion -- I thought that'd be implied, but I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: @eftshift0:  Huh...I could have sworn that I've seen it before, but the most recent example I'm looking at now conforms to your claim.

Comment: @eftshift0 `git show` by itself only works for one commit because the default argument is `HEAD`. I've updated the answer to explain how to tell `git` how to use more commits.

Comment: That's interesting, actually. Now, if you use 3 dots, I bet that (just like with diff) you do not have to look for the last common ancestor. You should be able to do `git show --name-only upstream-branch...feature-branch`

Comment: @eftshift0 That works well too. In fact, it looks like you don't even need to specify `feature-branch` if that's the current branch.